# How do I configure dual sided printing on a Brother 2270DW?

Tags: 11.10, printing

When I want to print something, I don't get the option to print on both sides of a paper although my printer supports this feature. How can I fix this? Do I have to download a proprietary driver?

My printer is a Brother 2270DW.